# Why scala compiler failes to compile this simple shapeless code?

Tags: scala, shapeless

```
import shapeless._; import labelled._;
object CreateField {
  type OptionalField[K <: Symbol, T] = FieldType[K, Option[T]]

  def pure[K <: Symbol, T](key: Witness.Aux[K], v: Option[T]): OptionalField[K, T] = {
    field[K](v) 
  }
}
```

The complain was

> found   : v.type (with underlying type Option[T]) [error]  required:
>   shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[K,Option[T]] with Option[T]

However, if you specify the type for field[K].apply[Option[T]] it compiles, or if you simply first set it to a val and return that val, that is the following method body compiles:

```
 def pure[K <: Symbol, T](key: Witness.Aux[K], v: Option[T]): OptionalField[K, T] = {
    val f = field[K](v)
    f
  }
}
```

If you don't use the OptionalField type alias, it also compiles.

Is this a ScalaC bug or it's just the way scalaC infers type is somehow  incompatible with this `field` method from shapeless?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.